# Apply Gmail filters to sublabels only

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, gmail-search

I'm migrating my email to Gmail and I'm trying to apply filters as follows.

```
Me.com
 - Me
   - Job Promos
   - Education
```

I would like to filter out certain @ domains and stick them into either `Job Promos` or `Education` and have everything else which doesn't fit those categories get filtered under the `Me` label.

The way I'm trying to do this is as follows.

I have one filter for `Job Promos` as follows (the `Education` one is similar, so I'll ignore it for brevity):

```
Matches: from:(*@indeedemail.com | *@angel.co | *@allegisgroup.com | *@hired.com | JobAlerts@jsalerts.careerbliss.com | *@stonehengestaffing.com | *@jsalerts.matchedjobs.com | *@lempop.com | *@stonehengestaffing.com | *@ziprecruiter.com | *monster.com | @cybercoders.com

Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Me.com/Me/Job Promos", Never send it to Spam, Categorize as Promotions
```

This catches MOST of the job promos (it seems to have some difficulty with things I'm either CC's or BCC'd on, but that's another issue.

I then have another filter that says

```
to:(me@me.com)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Me.com/Me"
```

Now based on the logic of this, of course it's going to be doing what it's doing: applying the label `Me.com/Me`AND also applying the `Me.com/Me/Job Promos` to the emails that match the specified senders. It's clear to me why it's doing what it's doing.

The problem is, I'm not sure how to make it do what I want, which is:

`If matches "Me@Me.com" AND NOT in the "Job Promos" filter THEN move to Me.com/Me`

Answer (score 0):

You need simply negate the criteria for the other search so  your search

```
to:(me@me.com)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Me.com/Me"
```

Becomes

```
to:(me@me.com) -from:({indeedemail angel.com allegisgroup hired.com jsalerts.careerbliss.com stonehengestaffing.com jsalerts.matchedjobs.com lempop.com stonehengestaffing ziprecruiter monster.com cybercoders}) 

Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Me.com/Me"
```

- `{}` indicates that the terms within are optional, and eliminates the need for `||` or `OR`
- `()` groups terms together.
- `*` is meaningless and the `@` is also unnecessary when searching by domain name.